# Create meCard qr code in iOS?

Tags: ios, contacts, qr-code, addressbook, vcf-vcard

I have a ready code which can create `vCard` qr code. But I can't find info how to create `meCard`.

[Difference between vCard and meCard](https://www.devicemedia.ca/blog/whats-the-difference-between-a-vcard-and-a-mecard/)

Additionally `vCard` is easier because its support is built-in into `AddressBook.framework` and `Contacts.framework` but `meCard` even didn't mentioned in these frameworks.

How to create this `meCard` qr code?

Answer (score 0):

I found this online: https://theqrplace.wordpress.com/2011/05/02/qr-code-tech-info-mecard-format/

Looks like it gives you the info you need.

Comment: Thanks but I have a better one: https://www.nttdocomo.co.jp/english/service/developer/make/content/barcode/function/application/addressbook/index.html
I hoped to find any iOS example. But it seems to be great to find the example on any programming language.

Comment: It looks like a pretty simple format. Just write some code that takes your address book entry and converts it to text in that format. It should not take long.

Comment: It could be a problem because it is slightly unclear what to do for example if I have multiple values/no value for any key